# How to get data from pivot table which has ids from three tables

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have three tables call Users, Services, Categories and pivot table call professionals.
Also four models for all tables.

```
User: Id, name
Services: id, service_name
Categories: id, service_id, category_name
Professionals: id, user_id, service_id, category_id

Relationships
User has many Categories
Service has many categories
category can have one service
category belongs to many users
```

```
$result = Professional::where('user_id’,’=‘,54)->get();
```

Above command give data like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_id": 54,
    "service_id": 8,
    "category_id": 20
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "user_id": 54,
    "service_id": 10,
    "category_id": 23
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "user_id": 54,
    "service_id": 9,
    "category_id": 21
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "user_id": 54,
    "service_id": 10,
    "category_id": 22
}
```

Please help me to get data from Professionals table with categories and services details related to a user, guide me how to make relations on models